# Which garden planner is image from? Which garden planner you would recommend for newbie person?

Tags: landscaping, design

So I found this plan, but I would modify it. Which app would you recommend?

[image]

I would make a medow like this:

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8JjyHfOMJ8

Answer (score 1):

I would get some different color sticky notes and a few pieces of graph paper and go from there.

I know you are thinking that software is the answer but the time to learn the software and adjust the presets for your climate zone is usually longer than the time to do it by hand.

Your other best tool is the local garden center because they know what grows in your area.  The good ones will tell you what does and doesn't last.

For example, in my area grocery stores will be happy to sell you Japanese Maples and Standard form Euonymus Colorata but you never see them in people's gardens because they are not reliably hardy in my area.

Comment: Wise advice for a newbie with big plans. Also, what does the garden now have growing? I'd work around the trees already there, and bring in a landscaper. As the answer says, local nurseries will happily advise and sell you material that suits you.